# Primefaces Component Not Calling Action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a command button component that is calling some action in my bean. When I test on my local weblogic server (v12.1.2.0.0) the action is called correctly. However, when I deploy to the dev weblogic server (v12.1.1.0) the action is never called. I also get similar results when using actionListener instead of action.

What might be causing the action to fail in the older version that is not present in the newer version? Are there any potential work arounds?

Here is the .xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="pagebody">

        <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="script.js" />

        <h:body>
            <h:form id="uploadform" prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <center>
                    <h2>File Upload</h2>
                    <br />
                    <p:commandButton value="Choose" action="#{uploadViewBean.chooseFile}" icon="ui-icon-plus"/>
                </center>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And the method that is called in the bean is simply

```
public void chooseFile() {
    try {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Data Tables", "txt", "csv", "xlsx"));
        jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        int returnVal = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            setTheFile(jfc.getSelectedFile());              
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(
                        ex.toString()));
    }
}
```

And yes, I know primefaces has a file chooser component I can use instead but I need to display the file chooser this way for a reason. That is not the issue I would like to focus on.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error on server or console of browser, if yes please put here, because code is fine.

Comment: Using a swing based file chooser is not the right thing to do in a REMOTE webapp. In a local server it works 'by accident' but it still is a design flaw, so yes, it **IS** the thing to focus on. Oh and it won't work with a plain jsf commandButton either so it is not a PrimeFaces, not a weblogic nor a JSF issue. It's a design flaw

Answer (score 0):

The issue existed between the version of PrimeFaces being used and the weblogic server version. A PrimeFaces update to 6.2 caused the error to go away.